# How to implement a navigation bar for popup dialog in IOS?

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a small UI dialog box (UIView) I will be showing at one point (in fact a pop-up over a mapkit map.  In this dialog I wish to have a navigation bar at the top that let's a user step through different data item (so a Back/Next set of buttons in the navigation bar).

**Question**: Should I look to try to utilise an IOS UINavigationBar and/or UINavigationController etc to build this little pop up?  Or should I just build this in XCode by hand (e.g. draw a navigation bar and put normal buttons in myself).   [Also if you can let me know why re your response so I can learn].

Background: At the moment I have an XIB dialog box in XCode which I have size set to "freeform", and then I instantiate this using:

```
calloutView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("GCCallout", owner: self, options: nil).first as! GCCallout
```

Comment: I'd say just make the root view controller of the pop up to be a navigation controller. This saves you not only time, but it's already got everything you want, so it'd be easier for you.

Comment: is this the root view controller of the pop up only you mean?  i.e. just wanting to understand your suggestion in terms of the main View Controller I have, which hosts the MapKit map, as opposed to the UIView I though up (the one in question) when a map pin is pushed?

Comment: When you push the pin, you should load a new uiview that contains a navigation controller so that it is easier to manipulate. You could also try going on iTunes U and looking for iOS 8/9 development classes. Those usually cover doing map applications

Comment: ok thanks - I'm ok with MapKit now, so I guessing I need to read up about how (in IOS development) how to load UIViews with controllers then as I haven't done this.  i.e. there would be nothing specific about MapKit itself in your suggestion is there?

Comment: No I'm not too sure about map kit, as I've never really dabbled with it. Read up in apples iBooks developer book if you wanna get the best tutorial for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, it depends on your dialog box requirement

You mentioned, that you need back and next button in navigation bar, as I understand, you simply want to manipulate the data in dialog box or do some operation using it.

If you would want series of view controllers inside dialog box, pushing after each other, then only navigation controller would be good to use in your dialog box

Otherwise, using it simply for navigation bar would be overkill.

UINavigationControlker is a Container Controller and is optimized for keeping view controllers in stack and pop them up.

I suggest, go for custom UIView from xib or if dialog box have much code to handle than, implement your dialog box in view controller, and add it as child view controller.

Comment: I'm starting to come to that conclusion too - how about just re-using the UI elements in Xcode in my custom dialog box across the top?  Any way of using items such as "navigation item", "bar button item", "tab bar item", "fixed space bar button item"?

Comment: Yes, simply Add UIToolbar on top of your dialog box, and then you can simply drag and drop all UIBarButton items inside it.